# Gradle sync prevents app from running

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to move a project folder from one location to another and change the folder name.

For various reasons version control was not possible so I have the following structure: MyApp\Version 1.xx\ and in this folder I have more folders named 1.0.1, 1.0.2 etc.

I also have another folder called MyApp that I want to copy into MyApp\Version 1.xx\ and rename it to 1.0.5.

Unfortunately, I am stuck with the following message: "Gradle files have changed since last project sync".

If I try to sync, the message pops up again in a few seconds. If I try to build/debug the project, I get this:

[image]

I also tried to create a new empty project with the same name into the desired folder and add the layouts and classes there but if I try to run the app I get these:

[image]

I tried Clean, Invalidate Cache and Restart, deleting and recreating Gradle files as well as most of the solutions provided around here, without any luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: "If I try to sync, the message pops up again in a few seconds. If I try to build/debug the project, I get this" -- try a command-line build, and see if that gives you anything more to go on. Otherwise, for that project (module? whatever), delete your `.gradle/`, `.idea/`, and `build/` directories, plus `.iml` files, and try re-importing into Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. I already tried deleting those directories and opening the project as well as importing it (without deleting the directories) again and it didn't work out. However, importing it after deleting everything did the trick. Unfortunately I cannot upvote your comment for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of CommonsWare, from the comments)*.

> If I try to sync, the message pops up again in a few seconds. If I try to build/debug the project, I get this"

Try a command-line build, and see if that gives you anything more to go on. Otherwise, for that project (module? whatever), delete your `.gradle/`, `.idea/`, and `build/` directories, plus `.iml` files, and try re-importing into Android Studio.